# module 'torch' has no attribute 'SymInt

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pytorch, torchvision

I wanted to test the "segment-anything" package, but ran into a problem when initializing the modules. When I initialize them, an error appears that torch does not have the SymInt attribute.
Unworked line: `from segment_anything import sam_model_registry, SamAutomaticMaskGenerator, SamPredictor`
Final problem text: "module 'torch' has no attribute 'SymInt'"

I tried different available versions of torchvision and torch.